# Unable to compile Gammu on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: c, osx-mountain-lion, gammu

I am trying to install Gammu on my Mac Machine. I already have cmake installed & also Apple Developer Command Line Tools.

When I run `./configure`, I get following :

```
Avi-MacBook-Pro:gammu-1.32.0 avi$ ./configure
Wrapper script for configuring CMake for Gammu.

This provides limited compatibility with configure, if you want full
configuration control, use directly CMake. More information about CMake
is available at <http://www.cmake.org>.

-- Configuring Gammu 1.32.0
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND) 
-- MySQL not found.
-- Found PostgreSQL: /usr/include, /usr/lib/libpq.dylib
-- libdbi not found.
-- Could NOT find Libintl (missing:  LIBINTL_INCLUDE_DIR LIBINTL_LIB_FOUND) 
-- glib-2.0 not found.
-- gobject-2.0 not found.
-- Bluez not found.
-- Using OSX Bluetooth stack
-- Bluetooth support enabled
-- libusb-1.0 not found.
-- Nokia support enabled
-- Nokia MBUS2 protocol enabled
-- Nokia FBUS2 protocol enabled
-- Nokia FBUS2DLR3 protocol enabled
-- Nokia DKU2PHONET protocol enabled
-- Nokia DKU2AT protocol enabled
-- Nokia DKU5FBUS2 protocol enabled
-- Nokia FBUS2PL2303 protocol enabled
-- Nokia FBUS2BLUE protocol enabled
-- Nokia PHONETBLUE protocol enabled
-- Nokia BLUEFBUS2 protocol enabled
-- Nokia BLUEPHONET protocol enabled
-- Nokia 3320 and compatible phones support enabled
-- Nokia 650 and compatible phones support enabled
-- Nokia 61xx and compatible phones support enabled
-- Nokia 6510 and compatible phones support enabled
-- Force using 6210 frames for calendar for DCT4 phones disabled
-- Nokia 7110 and compatible phones support enabled
-- Nokia 9210 and compatible phones support enabled
-- Nokia 3650 and compatible phones support enabled
-- AT support enabled
-- AT protocol enabled
-- AT protocol over Bluetooth enabled
-- AT phones support enabled
-- Alcatel support enabled
-- Alcatel protocol enabled
-- Alcatel phones support enabled
-- OBEX compatible phones support enabled
-- OBEX protocol over Bluetooth enabled
-- Generic OBEX phones support enabled
-- AT with OBEX phones support enabled
-- Symbian phones support (S60) enabled
-- Symbian phones support (gnapplet) enabled
-- GNAPBUS protocol over Bluetooth enabled
-- Gnapplet phones support enabled
-- S60 phones support enabled
-- Cell Broadcast messages support enabled
-- Backup/Restore functions enabled
/var/lock is not writable, skipping locking tests!
-- Init script not being installed, install it by -DINSTALL_LSB_INIT=ON
-- Udev rules not being installed, install it by -DINSTALL_UDEV_RULES=ON
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/build-configure
```

When I run `make`, I get error :

```
Avi-MacBook-Pro:gammu-1.32.0 avi$ make
make -C build-configure
[  1%] Building C object helper/CMakeFiles/string.dir/string.o
In file included from /Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.c:1:
/Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.h:14:10: error: 'string.h'
      file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <string.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
         "string.h"
/Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.h:39:57: error: unknown type
      name 'size_t'
extern int strncasecmp (const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
                                                        ^
/Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.h:58:1: error: unknown type
      name 'wchar_t'
wchar_t         towlower                        (wchar_t c);
^
/Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.h:58:22: error: unknown type
      name 'wchar_t'
wchar_t         towlower                        (wchar_t c);
                                                 ^
In file included from /Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/helper/string.c:3:
/Users/avi/Desktop/gam/gammu-1.32.0/build-configure/helper/../include/gammu-unicode.h:18:10: fatal error: 
      'wchar.h' file not found
#include <wchar.h>
         ^
5 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [helper/CMakeFiles/string.dir/string.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [helper/CMakeFiles/string.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unrelated to CMake. Your C compiler does not find some headers that are defined in the C standard. That's weired and probably unrelated to Gammu.

Can you check whether you can compiler a simple hello word C test program that includes ? If that fails, you have to fix your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

it's missing a lot of files, you have to get several file that's missing, especially when you're using MAMP for your server. This is how I succeeded in installing gammu on my mac

To install gammu on Mac OS X, you need :
Mac OS X 10.8.4, 
Xcode 4.6.3, 
MAMP 2.1.4 & Mysql from mysql.com (for header and library files)
Gammu 1.33.0, 
Cmake 2.8.11.2 & install it using Homebrew package manager.

Install xcode with command line tools
Install MAMP

To install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Then, you can install cmake with:

```
$ brew install cmake
```

Download gammu

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gammu/files/gammu/1.33.0/gammu-1.33.0.tar.gz
```

Extract it and put in your home folder

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

when using MAMP :

MAMP doesn't have the necessary header files and library files so to get them just install mysql from mysql.com choose 64 bit osx 10.8

Copy header files from a from-source installation or a binary installation that included them (the stock MySQL binary for Mountain Lion included these) from /usr/local/mysql/include to /Applications/MAMP/Library/include.

to access the /usr/local you can type /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib in safari & click enter, you'll be directed to that file in the finder.

```
$ /bin/ls -1 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient* | xargs -t -n1 -I% ln -fs % /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/

ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.a /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
ln -fs /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
```

Now, let’s compile gammu with mysql support, extract gammu as usual, edit cmake/FindMySQL.cmake, add your MAMP mysql path, it should be look like this:

```
find_program(MYSQL_CONFIG mysql_config
${MYSQL_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH}
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/bin/
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
/Applications/MAMP/Library
)
```

Then, let’s configure cmake:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DMYSQL_LIBRARIES=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I hope this will help you to install gammu.